# Append file on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am working on a requirement where I have to constantly append the file on S3 bucket. The scenario is similar to rolling log file. Once the script(or any other method) starts writing the data to the file, until I stop it, the file should be appended on S3 bucket. I searched several ways but could not find the solution. Most the available resources says how to upload the static file to S3 but not the dynamically generated file.

Comment: If these are logs, or like logs, then consider storing to CloudWatch Logs instead of S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 objects can only be overwritten, not appended-to.  It's not possible.

Once created, objects are durably stored and immutable.  Any "change" to an object requires that the object be replaced.

While it is possible to stream a file into S3, this doesn't accomplish the purpose either, because the object you are creating is not accessible until the upload is finalized.